# How is Polygon a scaling solution to Ethereum?

Tags: polygon

Polygon blocks appear to happen 6 times faster, and each block has on average 33% more gas.

In total, this means Polygon can process 8 times as much gas as Ethereum.

How can one even call this a scaling solution?

Shouldn't the gas prices just rise to be at least one eight of Ethereum's (which is practically just as bad) once people start using it?

Is the fact that Polygon is currently used less than Ethereum the only thing going for it?

Is there any actual real scalability benefit that Polygon offers compared to Ethereum, rather than just a little extra gas?

If not, are there plans to improve that?